# elasticsearch: aggregations on nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have some documents like those (samples is a nested object in the _mapping):

```
"_source": {
   "samples": [
      {
         "name": "A",
         "d": 0.1
      },
      {
         "name": "B",
         "d": 0.2
      },
      ... A THOUSAND SAMPLES
      {
         "name": "N",
         "d": 197
      }
   ],
   "Date": "2015-10-01T01:06:59+0000",
   "fwot": "ENGINE1"
}
```

and

```
"_source": {
   "samples": [
      {
         "name": "A",
         "d": 0.2
      },
      {
         "name": "C",
         "d": 10032
      },
      ... A THOUSAND SAMPLES NOT NECESSARILY THE SAME FOR ALL THE DOCUMENTS
      {
         "name": "N",
         "d": 292
      }
   ],
   "Date": "2015-10-01T01:07:59+0000",
   "fwot": "ENGINE1"
}
```

and I want to make aggregations stats on `N` to make histograms by buckets of sample `A`

I start with a filter on the documents to get the relevant docs

```
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "samples", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [ 
                  { "match": { "samples.name": "A" }},
                  { "match": { "samples.name": "N"}}
                ]
          }}}
        }
```

but now, what could be the aggregation part?

```
"aggs": {
    "samples": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "samples"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "n_stats_by_a": {
              "histogram": { 
              // ONLY ON SAMPLES WHERE name='A'
                "field":    "samples.d",
                "interval": 0.1 
              }
              //DO A METRICS ON samples.d ONLY ON SAMPLES WHERE name='N'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like something like that as output

```
"aggregations": {
  "samples": {
     "doc_count": 57716,
     "n_stats_by_a": {
        "doc_count": 177,
        "agg_histogram": {
           "buckets": [
              {
                 "key": "A_0.0_TO_0.1",
                 "avg_N": 182.332 //average of N when A between 0 and 0.1
              },
              {
                 "key": "A_0.1_TO_0.2",
                 "avg_N": 198.332 //average of N when A between 0.1 and 0.2
              }
              ...
           ]
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "samples": {
     "nested": {
        "path": "samples"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "n_stats_by_a": {
           "filter": {
              "term": {
                 "samples.name": "A"
              }
           },
           "aggs": {
              "agg_histogram": {
                 "histogram": {
                    "field": "samples.d",
                    "interval": 0.1
                 },
           "aggs" : {
            "avg_value" : { "avg" : {"field" : "samples.d"} } 
                }
              }
           }
        },
        "n_stats_by_d": {
           "filter": {
              "term": {
                 "samples.name": "N"
              }
           },
           "aggs": {
              "agg_histogram": {
                 "histogram": {
                    "field": "samples.d",
                    "interval": 0.1
                 }
               }
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This would  lead to 2 aggregations with buckets `n_stats_by_d` and `n_stats_by_a`. 

Now, I don't know how to get the average value of `N` in each bucket of `n_stats_by_a`

Comment: Please specify the sample output??

Comment: I don't understand the way it works: `"avg" : {"field" : "samples.d"}` is the average, that's OK. But the average of what? To me, reading this, it is the average of A (maybe worse: all the samples?). I need the average of N. I cannot see where you specify the field of the nested from which you want the average computed out

Comment: average for `sample name A` within every range(histogram) bucket

Comment: Therefore, any hint on having N average by sample.name='A' histogram buckets?